# Use RewiteRule with $_GET variables

Tags: .htaccess

So I have this template engine, and now I want pretty Url's. But every possible rewriterule in my book is like "Suck it! I'm not gonna work". So I want to ask you guys for help.

This is the current .htacces

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /(.*)/$ /index.php?page=$1
```

Can any of you please tell me what's wrong with the code above? 
Thanks,

Robin

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do you seriously believe that comment is helpful in anyway for someone to track your problem and help you?

Comment: Provide answers to all of these questions: Q0. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess? Q4. Did you make sure that `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` are enabled?